# Joomla "No input file specified" also with SEO disabled

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I am finding some problems after the migration to a new hosting provider of my Joomla site.

I used Akeeba Backup and Akeeba Kickstart to restore the site to the newer hosting.
The process seems to have succeeded, infact I can access to the backend without problem.

The problem come in the frontend where I get the following error on every page: **No input file specified**.

I know this problem depends on the joomla SEO settings, so I tried all the solutions I found on the web:

- Disable all SEO settings
- Rename `.htaccess` to `htaccess.txt`
- Remove the **#** sign from the line `# RewriteBase /`
- Add `Options -MultiViews` after `+FollowSymLinks`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Solved, there where a path issue in my php.ini

Replace

```
open_basedir=/home/OLDdhostingusername/public_html:/tmp::/home/OLDhostingusername/temp_joomla:/home/OLDhostingusername/public_html/logs
```

With

```
open_basedir=/home/NEWhostingusername/public_html:/tmp::/home/NEWhostingusername/temp_joomla:/home/NEWhostingusername/public_html/logs
```

Comment: Wish I had find this answer earlier. I had also the same problem and solution was so obvious